# Converting more than one SVG element to PNG in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have a simple chart that uses 3 d3.js SVG elements to display different stuff. I want to convert that to PNG. I found this solution on here:

```
function saveImage(){

var html = d3.selectAll("svg")
    .attr("version", 1.1)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'"/>';
d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);
console.log(html);
};
```

Now this probably works fine, if i would only use one SVG element, but if i try this, i get this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 419: Extra content at the end of the document
```

Column 419 is, of course directly between the first closing < /svg> tag and the next opening < svg> tag.

Is it possible to convert all 3 elements into one picture using only javascript?

Comment: I decided to create a pdf from all the svgs to make it scaleable, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with d3.js ,

Before that, I have to know that, Does your code working well for single svg?
You got a error on multiple svg used right?

If it is, you will try the following code

```
function saveImage(){

var html = d3.selectAll("svg")
    .attr("version", 1.1)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .node().parentNode.innerHTML;
for(var i=0;i<html.length;i++)
{
var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html[i]);
var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'"/>';
d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);
console.log(html[i]);
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works when using a single svg. Yours doesn't but if i comment out all the other elements it works fine.

Comment: My code also working fine on single svg right,if it is ,I have to know the html.length value.If you using 4 svg,that value must be 4. Then push all imageData each svg and then drawImage on canvas then you will get all images into single image